# Regex to split a comma separated css class names string into array

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split a CSS class names string into array of CSS class names in JavaScript. All the below strings should produce the same array.

```
'lmn-button,lmn-button-primary' => ['lmn-button', 'lmn-button-primary']

'lmn-button, lmn-button-primary' => ['lmn-button', 'lmn-button-primary'] // Note the space after comma

'lmn-button ,lmn-button-primary' => ['lmn-button', 'lmn-button-primary'] // Note the space before comma

'  lmn-button ,lmn-button-primary' => ['lmn-button', 'lmn-button-primary'] // Note the space at start

'lmn-button ,lmn-button-primary  ' => ['lmn-button', 'lmn-button-primary'] // Note the space at end
```

Currently I'm using code to do that,

```
cssClassesString.split(',').map(cssClass => cssClass.trim());
```

But I believe regex would be a better solution that this right?

I got this regex by googling `/([^,]+)` but the result array has spaces in class names.

How can I improve the above regex to handle that?

Comment: I would suggest to avoid regex where string methods can do the job, but if you prefer regex, what about: `/([^, ]+)/` which means "any character but not space or comma, one or more times"?

Comment: or also `/([^,\s]+)/`...

Comment: Just use `var result = s.match(/[^,\s]+/g)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const arr = ' lmn-button ,lmn-button-primary'.trim().split(/\s*,\s*/);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: If there are spaces at start or end of the string  '   lmn-button ,lmn-button-primary  ', the regex is not working very well. I know I'm asking too much. Is it possible to handle that?

Answer (score 4):

You may simply extract all substrings that consist of 1+ chars other than whitespace and comma.

```
var result = s.match(/[^,\s]+/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GUYD2v/1).

The `[^...]` is a negated character class matching any char but the one(s) specified in the class. `,` matches commas and `\s` matches any whitespace chars, so `[^,\s]` matches any char but a comma and whitespace. `+` quantifier matches 1+ consecutive occurrences of such chars.

JS demo:

```js
var tests = ['lmn-button,lmn-button-primary', 'lmn-button, lmn-button-primary', 'lmn-button ,lmn-button-primary','  lmn-button ,lmn-button-primary', 'lmn-button ,lmn-button-primary  '];
var rx = /[^\s,]+/g;
for (var s of tests) {
  console.log(s, "=>", s.match(rx));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you use this

```js
console.log('lmn-button ,lmn-button-primary'.split(/[ ,.]+/));
```

Comment: This does not handle a string that starts or ends with spaces (or commas) -- in that case you would end up with empty strings in the array. I would use a `trim()` before the `split()` function. Also, using the `\s` whitespace char would handle embedded tabs.